# How to create a tabular layout in a Power BI Matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a Power BI dashboards that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the `subscriptionName` is hidden and you have to click on the `+` in order to open up and see the name of the subscription.

I would like to have the `SubscriptionId` and the `subscriptionName` on the same line without need to open up the next row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the formatting pane, turn off stepped layout.

[image]

On the matrix itself, click the split arrow icon.

[image]